# How do you aggregate a query based on a boolean field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this Article model for a news site with a boolean field called "sticky". The idea is that when the author writes an article and marks it as sticky it should always stay at the top of the list of articles. I wrote a template tag and here's my render method:

```
def render(self, context):
    context[self.varname] = self.model._default_manager.filter(current_issue__isnull=True, issue__isnull=True).live().order_by('-created_at')
    return ''
```

This query is where I want to aggregate the sticky articles at the top of the list. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean, aggregate them? What's your desired output/result?

Comment: Daniel, my desired output is to have the "sticky" articles on top of the article list and the rest of the articles under the sticky articles sorted by "-created_at". The sticky articles are sort of a "featured" type that will sit on top of all articles and remain there until a new one replaces it.

Answer (score 2):

Order by sticky, then order by created_at.

Comment: I've tried that, that does not work. When a new article is added it takes over and the sticky one is pushed down.

Comment: Um?  By "pushed down" you mean in your view?  If so, how is your view/template working?  

An alternative would be two have two variables that you pass from your view into your template, one for sticky articles, and one for non-sticky.